# ALAssetsLibrary-CustomPhotoAlbum ios 8

Tags: ios, photo, alassetslibrary

**Updated / rephrased question:**

In my project I use [ALAssetsLibrary-CustomPhotoAlbum](https://github.com/Kjuly/ALAssetsLibrary-CustomPhotoAlbum). While it worked fine on iOS 7, I never noticed when coding for iOS 8, it ended being broken. Broken as in not being able to recreate folders that were deleted with the same name.

It will create the folder if it starts as a new process where if you open app and it asks for photo permission.

My current code still saves the photo to said folder if I create the folder manually:

```
    [self.library saveImage:image toAlbum:@"NamedAlbum" withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        if (error!=nil) {
            NSLog(@"Big error: %@", [error description]);
        }
    }];
```

What I'm stuck on is the following:

```
[self.library saveImage:image toAlbum:@"NamedAlbum" completion:nil failure:^(NSError *error) {
    if (error!=nil) {
        NSLog(@"Big error: %@", [error description]);
    }
}];
```

It appears it changed the completion/failure block process, and I can't figure this out.

What do I need to do to link those up to the library?

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE 12/22** 
Seems I got ahead of myself when posting my answer, this only works sometimes. Will keep on digging.

```
// The completion block to be executed after image taking action process done
void (^completion)(NSURL *, NSError *) = ^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
    if (error) NSLog(@"!!!ERROR,  write the image data to the assets library (camera roll): %@",
                     [error description]);
    NSLog(@"*** URL %@ | %@ || type: %@ ***", assetURL, image, [assetURL class]);

};

void (^failure)(NSError *) = ^(NSError *error) {
    if (error == nil) return;
    NSLog(@"!!!ERROR, failed to add the asset to the custom photo album: %@", [error description]);
};

[self.assetsLibrary saveImage:image
                      toAlbum:albumName
                   completion:completion
                      failure:failure];
```

Answer (score 1):

While I do believe there is a bug in the SDK. What I have below seems to work fine on my 6+.

It may not be the "correct" way, but it's what worked from the example that was provided.

```
NSURL *imageURL = receivedURL;
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL]];
NSString *albumName = @"NamedAlbum";

// The completion block to be executed after image taking action process done
void (^completion)(NSURL *, NSError *) = ^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {

    if (error) NSLog(@"!!!ERROR,  write the image data to the assets library (camera roll): %@",
                     [error description]);
    NSLog(@"*** URL %@ | %@ || type: %@ ***", assetURL, image, [assetURL class]);

};

void (^failure)(NSError *) = ^(NSError *error) {
    if (error == nil) return;
    NSLog(@"!!!ERROR, failed to add the asset to the custom photo album: %@", [error description]);
};

[self.library saveImage:image
                      toAlbum:albumName
                   completion:completion
                      failure:failure];
```

Hope this helps somebody even though it's a shame that this question got down voted.